# Is it possible to have bash variables persist between runs

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, init-script

I am trying to create an init script which queries `losetup -f` for a free loop device. Within the init script I have a `start()` which queries `losetup -f` for the free loop device to setup some stuff, and there is also a `stop()`.

The problem I can't figure out is how can I store the output of `losetup -f` in a persistent matter which is safe from user accidents (overwriting environment variables, etc) so that when `stop()` is called at any point I can have access to this particular init scripts loop device that it was assigned.

The reason I need persistence on which loop device is assigned is that there are 2-3 init scripts which are going to be dealing with loop devices (at least 2 loop devices per init script) and each needs to keep track of itself.

Should I assign the output of the multiple `losetup -f` to a file so that I can read them back via loop when I need to detach/work with them? If so what is a standard directory for this kind of data.

Comment: Store it in a file under `/var/run`, or its newer equivalent `/run`.

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments I have created a solution:

```
start() {
    loop=$(losetup -f)
    echo "$loop" > /var/run/init-script-name.loop
    #continue to use $loop as the reference to your loop device
}

stop() {
    loop=$(cat /var/run/init-script-name.loop)
    rm /var/run/init-script-name.loop
    #continue to use $loop as the reference to this scripts loop device
}
```

This allows each init script to save its loop device to a file that it can reference if it needs to obtain the device it was assigned at a later date. If multiple devices are needed you can echo them all into the file (one per line) and use `while read -r /path/to/file` to generate an array like structure which you can iterate over.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could help.

Storing the vars,

```
declare -p var_name another_var more_vars > path_to_init_file
```

Retrieving,

```
source path_to_init_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered this great simple project (a rewritten fork).  Looks perfect.

https://github.com/imyller/kv-sh

- Tiny key-value database
- Configurable database directory (default: `~/.kv-sh`)
- Used by importing functions via `$ . ./kv-sh`
- Full database dump/restore
- Support for secondary read-only defaults database

```
    . ./kv-sh                  # import kv-sh functions (use default database directory; see
                                 configuration environment variables for available options)
    kvset <key> <value>        # assign value to key
    kvget <key>                # get value of key
    kvdel <key>                # delete key
    kvexists <key>             # check if key exists
    kvkeys {-l|-d|-a}          # list all keys (-l local only, -d default only, -a all (default))
    kvlist {-a}                # list all key/value pairs (-a all keys, including default)
    kvdump {-a}                # database dump (-a all keys, including default)
    kvimport                   # database import (overwrite)
    kvrestore                  # database restore (clear and restore)
    kvclear                    # clear database
```

**Defaults database**

`kv-sh` supports secondary read-only defaults database. If enabled, keys-value pairs from default value database are returned if local value is not specified.

Enable defaults database by setting `DB_DEFAULTS_DIR`:

```
DB_DIR="/tmp/.kv" DB_DEFAULTS_DIR="/tmp/.kv-default" . ./kv-sh
```